# Glide with GlidePalette not accepting center crop

Tags: android, android-glide, palette

I am using

**Glide and GlidePalette**

When I added GlidePalette dependency it gave me the following error

**Error:Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT**

But I solved it by adding these lines to the gradle in repositories

```
    jcenter() 
if (project.hasProperty('local.repo')) {
    maven { name 'glide-local'; url project.property('local.repo') }
} 
maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: 'libs'
```

Now I am unable to access  **centerCrop()**

Link to Screenshot of code : http://s33.postimg.org/u036zjuj3/Capture.png

The dependencies I added were

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.0.0'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Please help me out